# C# DataGridview ColumnHeader Multi Line Text Center or Right Alignment

Tags: c#, datagridview, multiline, text-alignment, columnheader

I am facing a problem in C# Datagridview that I have multi line text in the ColumnHeaders of that Datagridview and I want the text to be centered in both lines. Currently, its showing centered text only when there is single line, but in case of multiline, it behaves like this:

```
|L1        |
|L2 Text   |
```

And I want it to be appeared as

```
|    L1    |
| L2 Text. |
```

I tried properties

```
DG.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
DG.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

I don't have much points to upload image or screenshot, so sorry for that.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got it finally. This piece of code worked for me.

```
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;
dgv.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

In your gridview load method.

```
foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dgvYourGridName.Columns)
{
    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

}
```

Comment: No, this didn't work, there is no such event for Datagridview, so I tried it form Load event, but no changes. FYI, this is Virtual grid, so I have the property VirtualMode = true for this grid and I load the data in CellValueNeeded Event.

Comment: Check this..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But in this example, its resizing all Non Header Cells and I want to Align the text of Header Cell only, because its resizing is being done perfectly.

Comment: don't follow the example.Just try to extract what you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

I know for a GridView you can add HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" and TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" to the GridViewColumnHeader tag in the xaml.

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumnHeader 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" Content="Some String"/>
```

I assume something similar would work for DataGridView.